# Auto generated Index Columns is not exported in generated file( pdf , excel) using Jquery Datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have created a table using Datatable and also exported the data id pdf and excel.There is a column of Serial Number(S.No.) which index no. is 1.Table is working in the webpage.But when file is exporting header is showing of the serial number but number is not showing in the file. 
Please see the code below.
If there any solution.Please let me know.
Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var t = $('#log').DataTable( {           
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
   {
       extend: 'pdf',
       title: 'Activity Report',
       footer: true,
       exportOptions: {
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
        }
   },
   {
       extend: 'excel',
       title: 'Activity Report',
       exportOptions: {
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
       footer: false
   } , 
   {
       extend: 'print',
       title: 'Login Activity Report',
       exportOptions: {
            columns: [1,2,3,4,5]
        },
       footer: true
   }       
]  
});
  t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
  t.column(1, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
     });
    }).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understood, you need index column to be printed on pdf page which is being displayed on your webpage, i.e it should always start with 1.

```
    t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        t.column(1, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
            t.cell(cell).invalidate('dom');
            });
        }).draw();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your column names are coming from database and you are assigning value to all columns at runtime. I'm also assuming that your column names are as follows NAME, ACCOUNT, AGE, SALARY then while rendering your columns to database add one null column in it called `srno` by following way.

```
 "aoColumns": [
   {
             "data": "srno",
             "defaultContent":  "" // WHICH IS CHANGED TO SR NO 
   },]
```

Here we are assigning null value to column 0. so in export option you'll have to change it like

```
  exportOptions: {
        columns: [0,1,2,3,4]
    }
```

we are doing this because columns is an array in datatables jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var t = $('#log').DataTable( {           
 dom: 'Blfrtip',
 buttons: [
 {
   extend: 'pdf',
   title: 'Activity Report',
   footer: true,
   exportOptions: {
        columns: [0,1,2,3,4]
    }
  },
 {
   extend: 'excel',
   title: 'Activity Report',
   exportOptions: {
        columns: [0,1,2,3,4]
    },
   footer: false
  } , 
  {
   extend: 'print',
   title: 'Login Activity Report',
   exportOptions: {
        columns: [0,1,2,3,4]
   },
   footer: true
  }       
]
"aoColumns": [
   {
             "data": "srno",
             "defaultContent":  "" // WHICH IS CHANGED TO SR NO 
   },
   { "mData": "NAME" },
   { "mData": "ACCOUNT" },
   { "mData": "AGE" },
   { "mData": "SALARY" }
    ]  
 });
 t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
 t.column(1, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
    cell.innerHTML = i+1;
  });
  }).draw();
});
```

Today I've faced same issue and after some R&D I came to this solution. Though it is too late to solve your problem but I hope it will help other readers of our community.

Comment: i have same issue here.

Answer (score 0):

For serial number columns we need to change the values are string while exporting it based on as per reference datatables forum [link](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/outputFormat-orthogonal.html)

Below Solution it works

```
$(function()
    {
        var oTable = $('#ReportsOrdersTable').DataTable({
        bFilter: false,
        dom: 'lBfrtip',
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth:true,
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: { orthogonal: 'export' }
            }
        ],
        ajax: {
            url: 'reports/report_customer_order_list',
            type: 'POST',
            data: function (d) {
                d.from         = $('input[name=from]').val();
                d.to           = $('input[name=to]').val();
                d.order_status = $('#order_status').val();
            },
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
               targets  : 'no-sort',
               orderable: false,
        }],
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        columns: [
                { data: 'id', name: 'id', render: function (data, type, row) {
                return type === 'export' ?
                    data.toString() :
                    data;
                }},
                { data: 'firstname', name: 'firstname' },
                { data: 'email', name: 'email' },
                { data: 'booking_count', name: 'booking_count',render: function (data, type, row) {
                return type === 'export' ?
                    data.toString() :
                    data;
                } },
                { data: 'payments_amount', name: 'payments_amount' },
            ],            
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Auto-generated Index Columns is not exported in a generated file(pdf, excel) using Jquery Datatable

```
t.on('draw', function () {
         t.rows({ search: 'applied', order: 'applied', filter: 'applied' }).data().each(function (d, i) {
             d[0] = i + 1;
         });
     });

 t.on('order.dt search.dt', function () {
     t.column(0, { search: 'applied', order: 'applied' }).nodes().each(function (cell, i) {
          cell.innerHTML = i + 1;
     });
 }).draw(false);
```

this function working fine